# using jquery :selected selector with next / previous arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to set up small web application for online `font` preview purposes. Until now everything goes fine. I've made select box (works fine), test text-area (works fine), font-sizer (works fine), check-boxes for bold, italic... (works fine) which contains lists of fonts. When I choose one of font from select list all contents (predefined text) on page is changed and that`s OK, but I decided to add arrows (next and previous) for fast changes which also works but some of elements are not changed on button click.

What is the actual problem?

When I choose font from select list all is changed, but when I use those buttons for next/prev H1, and page title don't want to change because I need to show font name in page Heading as well on page TITLE.

here is : http://jsfiddle.net/S8PwY/

Can someone check this scripts and point me where is problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fontpicker").change(function() {
    $font = $('.fontpicker option:selected').val();
    $('.font_preview').css('fontFamily', $font);
});
$(".fontpicker").change(function() {
    $font = $('.fontpicker option:selected').val();
    $('.name').css('fontFamily', $font);
});



//min font size
var min = 10;

//max font size
var max = 60;

//grab the default font size
var reset = $('textarea').css('fontSize');

//font resize these elements
var elm = $('textarea');

//set the default font size and remove px from the value
var size = str_replace(reset, 'px', '');

//Increase font size
$('a.fontSizePlus').click(function() {

    //if the font size is lower or equal than the max value
    if (size <= max) {

        //increase the size
        size++;

        //set the font size
        elm.css({
            'fontSize': size
        });
    }

    //cancel a click event
    return false;

});

$('a.fontSizeMinus').click(function() {

    //if the font size is greater or equal than min value
    if (size >= min) {

        //decrease the size
        size--;

        //set the font size
        elm.css({
            'fontSize': size
        });
    }

    //cancel a click event
    return false;

});

//Reset the font size
$('a.fontReset').click(function() {

    //set the default font size    
    elm.css({
        'fontSize': reset
   }



$('.selector').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    if (checked) {
        $('.font_preview, textarea').addClass(value);
    } else {
        $('.font_preview, textarea').removeClass(value);
    }
});

$("#next").click(function() {
    $("#mycars").val($("#mycars > option:selected").next().val());
    $font = $('.fontpicker option:selected').val();
    $('.font_preview').css('fontFamily', $font);
    $('.name').css('fontFamily', $font);

});

$("#prev").click(function() {
    $("#mycars").val($("#mycars > option:selected").prev().val());
    $font = $('.fontpicker option:selected').val();
    $('.font_preview').css('fontFamily', $font);
    $('.name').css('fontFamily', $font);
});

 $("select").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
          });
      $("title,h1.name,th.name").text(str);
    })
    .trigger('change');
```

Comment: can u paste the html code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @ThulasiRam it is pasted

Comment: @ThulasiRam you made same thing as I do...there is same problem (font name wont change). Your and my buttons works in any case but there is problem with other thing...se my JS FIDDLE

Comment: Does this work -> http://jsfiddle.net/salman/S8PwY/2/

Comment: @Marko i do not understand u r problem.

Comment: u r asking if i click next h1 title text should be changed?

Comment: @ThulasiRam yes that`s right. This solution works if I choose font from select box (list) than h1 title text is changed in appropriated font-family and font name. Bit when I use next/prev buttons only font-family is changed without font name.

If you try use select box you will understand what is changed on H1 title text. This also need to be applied on prev/next buttons but it seems that is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code can be consolidated and fixed as follows:

```
$(".fontpicker").change(function() {
    $font = $('.fontpicker option:selected').val();
    $('.name').css('fontFamily', $font);
    $('.font_preview').css('fontFamily', $font);
    $("title,h1.name,th.name").text($font);
}).change();

$("#next").click(function() {
    $(".fontpicker").val($(".fontpicker >option:selected").next().val()).change();
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
    $(".fontpicker").val($(".fontpicker >option:selected").prev().val()).change();
});
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8PwY/5/)

Comment: Only one problem is active now...When you reach to the end of the list of fonts using next button you must use prev button to return to the start of list (or you can use RESET button). Is it possible to add constant loop on this next/prev buttons?

Comment: @ Beetroot-Beetroot - Also whole script does not work in IE at all

Comment: @Marko, be sure to delete your `$("select").change` handler. The above code supersedes it.

Comment: @Marko, from what you say, I think that `$("#fontpicker >option:selected").next()` must work differently in different browsers. `...next()` wraps in Opera, though `...(prev())` doesn't. There may be a better way achieve next/prev.

Comment: Eeek IE! I'll have a look at it.

Comment: when I deleted $("select").change handler now also loop works. But it seems that nothing is work in IE and there also few limitations in Opera :(

Comment: O yes! This is it! Thanks a lot Beetroot-Beetroot. Great coding..it seems that code is a lot smaller than before. From big messy code to nice one :)

Comment: You've probably still got problems with font-size reset. If so, then peek [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmSUu/2/) for an even tidier version.

Comment: Marko - yes we could either use stackoverflow chat or I could temporarily edit an email address into my answer above - either way, let me when you will be online.

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger `change` event in each `click` to make things changed:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    $("#mycars").val($("#mycars > option:selected").next().val()).trigger("change");
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
    $("#mycars").val($("#mycars > option:selected").prev().val()).trigger("change");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/u7dDw/